# How to popup image in CSS and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I tried to do popup image in the window in CSS and HTML that was successful.
But I tried to pop up one among images from the database by using PHP it pops up only the first image while I clicked to a different one.

The following is CSS

```
<style type="text/css"> 
#check:checked ~ label #cover {
  display: block;
}
#cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: none;
}
#box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 10px solid white;
}
</style>
```

And the following is my PHP

```
<? php
include("connection.php");
$que = mysql_query("select picture from pictures");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($que)) {
  $picture = $row['picture'];
  echo '<input type="checkbox" id="check" style="display:none;">
<label for="check">
    <img src="/image/'.$picture.
  '" style="width:50px; height: 50px"/>
    </label>
<label for="check">
    <div id="cover">
    <div id="box">
    <img src="/image/'.$picture.
  '" style="width:380px; height: 380px"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    </label>';
} ?>
```

How can I pop up each image when I click it among many ones from database in PHP?

Please anyone can help me.

Comment: When you use an `id`, it's supposed to be *unique*. You have dozens of elements, all with the same `id`s.

Comment: I've read your question a few times now, and I still don't know what you want. There is no javascript provided at all, so I don't know what does/doesn't work. You need to provide a minimum working example, and explain what doesn't work, whilst describing what the desired effect should be

Comment: Actually I have a table which contains information and their images, so I want to display all that images, if I click one among them and then pops up it in window. I tried to do it in CSS and PHP but if I click any image it pops up the first image selected from from table

Comment: Please include the rendered markup and not the PHP. PHP isn't going to be your issue here with the feature you want to implement. The only way PHP could be at fault (which really isn't PHP's fault) is through the markup you output. Your issue is in your CSS. You can only use an ID once per page yet you have a loop outputting multiple IDs multiple times, make them unique or use classes.

Comment: I already told you what the problem is. Here's a version that works: https://jsfiddle.net/h4a8umu2/ To implement that, keep a counter variable in your PHP loop and add it to the `id`s.

Comment: Ok Chris, let me try and see if it will solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused as well.

Is something like this what you want?

```js
var str = '<img class="image-up-popper" src=":image:" />';
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += str
    .replace(':id:', i)
    .replace(
      ':image:',
      'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=' + Math.round(Math.random() * 10) + '&w=100&h=100'
    );

}
```

```css
.image-up-popper {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.image-up-popper:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```